# Creating directory structure in database and storing data in it

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, dropbox-api

I am stuck with how to create directory like structure in `sqlite` database.

```
private void listFilesForFolder(Entry list) throws DropboxException
    {
        for (Entry ent : list.contents)
        {
            if (ent.isDir)
             { 
                // Log.i("List",ent.fileName());
                // Log.i("Path",ent.path);
            Entry list1 = mDBApi.metadata(ent.path, 1000, null, true,null);
            listFilesForFolder(list1);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("List", ent.fileName());
                // Log.i("Path",ent.path);
            }
        }
}
```

This a function through which i am getting list of all files and folders recursively from dropbox account using dropbox core API in android.

Now how can i store these data in sqlite database in directory like structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE entry (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    parent_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    is_dir INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT fk_parent FOREIGN KEY ( parent_id ) REFERENCES entry( _id )
);
```

- both directories and files are saved in this table.
- if a directory or a file has a parent, it's parent's `_id` is saved to `parent_id`.
- if the entry is a directory the `is_dir` field is set to 1, else 0.

Comment: Now my issue is how would i store these data in database.. i mean sql queries..which queries to write in if and else block so that directory structure is maintained..
I am getting confused because of the recursive function..thanks

Comment: I edited my answer. My first answer did not account for directories inside directories. This one does.

Comment: regarding your question about the recursive function, please open a new question for it and refer to it here. thanks.